# Testing if a Integer can be expressed as a n bit Signed integer

Tags: c

I've been stuck on a C coding puzzle involving bitwise manipulations.

The goal is to take an int, and a number of bits n
And then return if that int can be expressed as a n-bit 2s compliment.

The restrictions are that you must be able to compare the original number to a manipulated number and the use of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and comparisons is not allowed

Id rather not a code solution, but ideas and maybe some nudges.
The puzzle mostly restricts you to Bitwise operations as division, modulus, multiplication; as well as well as (<, >, <=, >=) are not allowed

for Example
we are given the int 8, and n-5
some transformation must be made to a variable x such that (x == 8) will return true if 8 can be expressed as a 5 bit 2s compliment integer

I'm looking more for understanding than a solution.

Comment: The specification “The problem mostly restricts you to Bit shifts” is not proper. We need to know the **full** statement of the problem, not **mostly** what it says.

Comment: It's also unclear when you say "you must be able to **compare** the original number to ... and the use of ... **comparisons** is not allowed."

Comment: Given a number of bits, `n`, it is not difficult to work out an upper limit on the number of distinct values an `n`-bit integer can represent.   Then you can check if the value is less than or equal to `n`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That part is clear. The task is to produce an `int` `x` such that `x == t` evaluates to true if and only if the `int` `t` is representable in an `n`-bit two’s complement integer. No comparison may be used in producing `x`. The comparison in `x == t` is outside the task of producing `x` and is irrelevant.

Comment: Added the specifically restricted operations

Answer (score -3):

So take 3 as your number of bits: 0b1000.  Subtract 1.  That yields the pattern: 0b0111.

Now test 5: 0b101.  0b111 xor 0b101 yields 0b010.  negate the result: 0b101.  if that result matches the number you are testing so the answer is yes.

Now test 9: 0b1001.  0b0111 xor 0b1001 yields 0b1110.  That does not match, so the answer is no.

So I think the answer is along that line.  Do some bit operations to turn your question into a equality compare form, and yield you a result.

Comment: The question says "signed integer".

Comment: I commented before you added the last paragraph. But this isn't an answer, because it says you don't know what to do.

Comment: Interesting.  What is your interpretation of the question?

Comment: That's what we are waiting for, the proper question.